# Append stderr and stdout to file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, stdout, stderr

I have this:

```
npm install "$tgz_path"  &>> "$HOME/.r2g/logs/r2g.log";
```

but that is syntactically incorrect.
How do I append stdout+stderr to that log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is valid in bash. From man bash:

> The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
>
> ```
> &>>word
> ```

A more basic way to write it (that works in more shells) will be:

```
$ npm install "$tgz_path" >>word 2>&1 "$HOME/.r2g/logs/r2g.log";
```

Comment: yeah maybe bash3 can't do the first one, I get a syntax error with bash3